# Javascript is not working after clicking on html <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pinch/zoom code want to execute after click on html  tag. The code works fine when I insert `<div class="zoom">` directly into the image, but it does not work after I insert  indirectly by clicking a html tag + javascript.

The idea is that the pinch/zoom code will only be executed when I click on the image. So how to fix javascript is not loading after clicking on html  tag? Does anyone have any suggestions for me? I will appreciate you a lot!

Thanks in advance!

Below is what I have done.

```js
// Click on image and add class to pinch/zoom
$(document).ready(function(e) {
if (typeof jQuery.fn.live == 'undefined' || !(jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.live))) {
  jQuery.fn.extend({
    live: function (event, callback) {
      if (this.selector) {
      jQuery(document).on(event, this.selector, callback);
      }
    }
  });
}
$('a.img').click(function(){
  var link_img = $(this).attr('href');
  $('body').append('<div class="zoom"><img border="0" src="'+link_img+'" data-original-width="540" data-original-height="720" /></div>');
  return false;
});
});

// Code pinch/zoom
"use strict";

zoom();

function zoom(classNames, settings) {
    classNames = (typeof(classNames) !== 'undefined' && Object.keys(classNames).length ? classNames : {});
    settings = (typeof(settings) !== 'undefined' && Object.keys(settings).length ? settings : {});
    var C_scaleDefault = settings["scaleDefault"] || 2;
    var C_scaleDifference = settings["scaleDifference"] || 0.5;
    var C_scaleMax = settings["scaleMax"] || 10;
    var C_scaleMin = settings["scaleMin"] || 1;
    var _active = classNames["active"] || "active";
    var _dataScale = "data-scale";
    var _dataTranslateX = "data-translate-x";
    var _dataTranslateY = "data-translate-y";
    var _transition = classNames["transition"] || "transition";
    var _visible = classNames["visible"] || "visible";
    var $container;
    var $element;
    var $zoom = document.getElementsByClassName(classNames["zoom"] || "zoom");
    var capture = false;
    var doubleClickMonitor = [null];
    var containerHeight;
    var containerWidth;
    var containerOffsetX;
    var containerOffsetY;
    var initialScale;
    var elementHeight;
    var elementWidth;
    var heightDifference;
    var initialOffsetX;
    var initialOffsetY;
    var initialPinchDistance;
    var initialPointerOffsetX;
    var initialPointerOffsetX2;
    var initialPointerOffsetY;
    var initialPointerOffsetY2;
    var limitOffsetX;
    var limitOffsetY;
    var mousemoveCount = 0;
    var offset;
    var pinchOffsetX;
    var pinchOffsetY;
    var pointerOffsetX;
    var pointerOffsetX2;
    var pointerOffsetY;
    var pointerOffsetY2;
    var scaleDirection;
    var scaleDifference;
    var targetOffsetX;
    var targetOffsetY;
    var targetPinchDistance;
    var targetScale;
    var touchable = false;
    var touchCount;
    var touchmoveCount = 0;
    var doubleTapMonitor = [null];
    var widthDifference;
    for (var i = 0; i < $zoom.length; i++) {
        $container = $zoom[i];
        $element = $container.children[0];
        $element.setAttribute(_dataScale, 1);
        $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateX, 0);
        $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateY, 0);
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $zoom.length; i++) {
            $container = $zoom[i];
            $element = $container.children[0];

            addClass($element, _visible);
        }
        window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < $zoom.length; i++) {
                $container = $zoom[i];
                $element = $container.children[0];
                if (hasClass($container, _active) === false) {
                    continue;
                }
                containerHeight = $container.clientHeight;
                containerWidth = $container.clientWidth;
                elementHeight = $element.clientHeight;
                elementWidth = $element.clientWidth;
                initialOffsetX = parseFloat($element.getAttribute(_dataTranslateX));
                initialOffsetY = parseFloat($element.getAttribute(_dataTranslateY));
                targetScale = C_scaleDefault;
                limitOffsetX = ((elementWidth * targetScale) - containerWidth) / 2;
                limitOffsetY = ((elementHeight * targetScale) - containerHeight) / 2;
                targetOffsetX = (elementWidth * targetScale) > containerWidth ? minMax(initialOffsetX, limitOffsetX * (-1), limitOffsetX) : 0;
                targetOffsetY = (elementHeight * targetScale) > containerHeight ? minMax(initialOffsetY, limitOffsetY * (-1), limitOffsetY) : 0;
                if (targetScale === 1) {
                    removeClass($container, _active);
                }
                $element.setAttribute(_dataScale, targetScale);
                $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateX, targetOffsetX);
                $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateY, targetOffsetY);
                moveScaleElement($element, targetOffsetX + "px", targetOffsetY + "px", targetScale);
            }
        });
    });
    massAddEventListener($zoom, "mousedown", mouseDown);
    massAddEventListener($zoom, "mouseenter", mouseEnter);
    massAddEventListener($zoom, "mouseleave", mouseLeave);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
        touchable = true;
    });
    massAddEventListener($zoom, "touchstart", touchStart);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", touchEnd);
    massAddEventListener($zoom, "wheel", wheel);
    function mouseEnter() {
        disableScroll();
    }
    function mouseLeave() {
        enableScroll();
    }
    function mouseDown(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (touchable === true || e.which !== 1) {
            return false;
        }
        $container = this;
        $element = this.children[0];
        initialPointerOffsetX = e.clientX;
        initialPointerOffsetY = e.clientY;
        if (doubleClickMonitor[0] === null) {
            doubleClickMonitor[0] = e.target;
            doubleClickMonitor[1] = initialPointerOffsetX;
            doubleClickMonitor[2] = initialPointerOffsetY;
            setTimeout(function() {
                doubleClickMonitor = [null];
            }, 300);
        } else if (doubleClickMonitor[0] === e.target && mousemoveCount <= 5 && isWithinRange(initialPointerOffsetX, doubleClickMonitor[1] - 10, doubleClickMonitor[1] + 10) === true && isWithinRange(initialPointerOffsetY, doubleClickMonitor[2] - 10, doubleClickMonitor[2] + 10) === true) {
            addClass($element, _transition);
            
            if (hasClass($container, _active) === true) {
                $element.setAttribute(_dataScale, 1);
                $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateX, 0);
                $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateY, 0);

                removeClass($container, _active);
                moveScaleElement($element, 0, 0, 1);
            } else {
                $element.setAttribute(_dataScale, C_scaleDefault);
                $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateX, 0);
                $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateY, 0);
                addClass($container, _active);
                moveScaleElement($element, 0, 0, C_scaleDefault);
            }
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                removeClass($element, _transition);
            }, 200);
            doubleClickMonitor = [null];
            return false;
        }
        offset = $container.getBoundingClientRect();
        containerOffsetX = offset.left;
        containerOffsetY = offset.top;
        containerHeight = $container.clientHeight;
        containerWidth = $container.clientWidth
        elementHeight = $element.clientHeight;
        elementWidth = $element.clientWidth;
        initialOffsetX = parseFloat($element.getAttribute(_dataTranslateX));
        initialOffsetY = parseFloat($element.getAttribute(_dataTranslateY));
        initialScale = minMax(parseFloat($element.getAttribute(_dataScale)), C_scaleMin, C_scaleMax);
        mousemoveCount = 0;
        capture = true;
    }
    function mouseMove(e) {
        if (touchable === true || capture === false) {
            return false;
        }
        pointerOffsetX = e.clientX;
        pointerOffsetY = e.clientY;
        targetScale = initialScale;
        limitOffsetX = ((elementWidth * targetScale) - containerWidth) / 2;
        limitOffsetY = ((elementHeight * targetScale) - containerHeight) / 2;
        targetOffsetX = (elementWidth * targetScale) <= containerWidth ? 0 : minMax(pointerOffsetX - (initialPointerOffsetX - initialOffsetX), limitOffsetX * (-1), limitOffsetX);
        targetOffsetY = (elementHeight * targetScale) <= containerHeight ? 0 : minMax(pointerOffsetY - (initialPointerOffsetY - initialOffsetY), limitOffsetY * (-1), limitOffsetY);
        mousemoveCount++;

        if (Math.abs(targetOffsetX) === Math.abs(limitOffsetX)) {
            initialOffsetX = targetOffsetX;
            initialPointerOffsetX = pointerOffsetX;
        }

        if (Math.abs(targetOffsetY) === Math.abs(limitOffsetY)) {
            initialOffsetY = targetOffsetY;
            initialPointerOffsetY = pointerOffsetY;
        }
        $element.setAttribute(_dataScale, targetScale);
        $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateX, targetOffsetX);
        $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateY, targetOffsetY);
        moveScaleElement($element, targetOffsetX + "px", targetOffsetY + "px", targetScale);
    }
    function mouseUp() {
        if (touchable === true || capture === false) {
            return false;
        }
        capture = false;
    }
    function touchStart(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.touches.length > 2) {
            return false;
        }
        $container = this;
        $element = this.children[0];
        offset = $container.getBoundingClientRect();
        containerOffsetX = offset.left;
        containerOffsetY = offset.top;
        containerHeight = $container.clientHeight;
        containerWidth = $container.clientWidth;
        elementHeight = $element.clientHeight;
        elementWidth = $element.clientWidth;
        initialPointerOffsetX = e.touches[0].clientX;
        initialPointerOffsetY = e.touches[0].clientY;
        initialScale = minMax(parseFloat($element.getAttribute(_dataScale)), C_scaleMin, C_scaleMax);
        touchCount = e.touches.length;
        if (touchCount === 1) {
            if (doubleTapMonitor[0] === null) {
                doubleTapMonitor[0] = e.target;
                doubleTapMonitor[1] = initialPointerOffsetX;
                doubleTapMonitor[2] = initialPointerOffsetY;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    doubleTapMonitor = [null];
                }, 300);
            } else if (doubleTapMonitor[0] === e.target && touchmoveCount <= 1 && isWithinRange(initialPointerOffsetX, doubleTapMonitor[1] - 10, doubleTapMonitor[1] + 10) === true && isWithinRange(initialPointerOffsetY, doubleTapMonitor[2] - 10, doubleTapMonitor[2] + 10) === true) {
                addClass($element, _transition);
                if (hasClass($container, _active) === true) {
                    $element.setAttribute(_dataScale, 1);
                    $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateX, 0);
                    $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateY, 0);
                    removeClass($container, _active);
                    moveScaleElement($element, 0, 0, 1);
                } else {
                    $element.setAttribute(_dataScale, C_scaleDefault);
                    $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateX, 0);
                    $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateY, 0);
                    addClass($container, _active);
                    moveScaleElement($element, 0, 0, C_scaleDefault);
                }
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    removeClass($element, _transition);
                }, 200);
                doubleTapMonitor = [null];
                return false;
            }
            initialOffsetX = parseFloat($element.getAttribute(_dataTranslateX));
            initialOffsetY = parseFloat($element.getAttribute(_dataTranslateY));
        } else if (touchCount === 2) {
            initialOffsetX = parseFloat($element.getAttribute(_dataTranslateX));
            initialOffsetY = parseFloat($element.getAttribute(_dataTranslateY));
            initialPointerOffsetX2 = e.touches[1].clientX;
            initialPointerOffsetY2 = e.touches[1].clientY;
            pinchOffsetX = (initialPointerOffsetX + initialPointerOffsetX2) / 2;
            pinchOffsetY = (initialPointerOffsetY + initialPointerOffsetY2) / 2;
            initialPinchDistance = Math.sqrt(((initialPointerOffsetX - initialPointerOffsetX2) * (initialPointerOffsetX - initialPointerOffsetX2)) + ((initialPointerOffsetY - initialPointerOffsetY2) * (initialPointerOffsetY - initialPointerOffsetY2)));
        }
        touchmoveCount = 0;
        capture = true;
    }
    function touchMove(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (capture === false) {
            return false;
        }
        pointerOffsetX = e.touches[0].clientX;
        pointerOffsetY = e.touches[0].clientY;
        touchCount = e.touches.length;
        touchmoveCount++;
        if (touchCount > 1) {
            pointerOffsetX2 = e.touches[1].clientX;
            pointerOffsetY2 = e.touches[1].clientY;
            targetPinchDistance = Math.sqrt(((pointerOffsetX - pointerOffsetX2) * (pointerOffsetX - pointerOffsetX2)) + ((pointerOffsetY - pointerOffsetY2) * (pointerOffsetY - pointerOffsetY2)));
            if (initialPinchDistance === null) {
                initialPinchDistance = targetPinchDistance;
            }
            if (Math.abs(initialPinchDistance - targetPinchDistance) >= 1) {
                targetScale = minMax(targetPinchDistance / initialPinchDistance * initialScale, C_scaleMin, C_scaleMax);
                limitOffsetX = ((elementWidth * targetScale) - containerWidth) / 2;
                limitOffsetY = ((elementHeight * targetScale) - containerHeight) / 2;
                scaleDifference = targetScale - initialScale;
                targetOffsetX = (elementWidth * targetScale) <= containerWidth ? 0 : minMax(initialOffsetX - ((((((pinchOffsetX - containerOffsetX) - (containerWidth / 2)) - initialOffsetX) / (targetScale - scaleDifference))) * scaleDifference), limitOffsetX * (-1), limitOffsetX);
                targetOffsetY = (elementHeight * targetScale) <= containerHeight ? 0 : minMax(initialOffsetY - ((((((pinchOffsetY - containerOffsetY) - (containerHeight / 2)) - initialOffsetY) / (targetScale - scaleDifference))) * scaleDifference), limitOffsetY * (-1), limitOffsetY);
                if (targetScale > 1) {
                    addClass($container, _active);
                } else {
                    removeClass($container, _active);
                }
                moveScaleElement($element, targetOffsetX + "px", targetOffsetY + "px", targetScale);
                initialPinchDistance = targetPinchDistance;
                initialScale = targetScale;
                initialOffsetX = targetOffsetX;
                initialOffsetY = targetOffsetY;
            }
        } else {
            targetScale = initialScale;
            limitOffsetX = ((elementWidth * targetScale) - containerWidth) / 2;
            limitOffsetY = ((elementHeight * targetScale) - containerHeight) / 2;
            targetOffsetX = (elementWidth * targetScale) <= containerWidth ? 0 : minMax(pointerOffsetX - (initialPointerOffsetX - initialOffsetX), limitOffsetX * (-1), limitOffsetX);
            targetOffsetY = (elementHeight * targetScale) <= containerHeight ? 0 : minMax(pointerOffsetY - (initialPointerOffsetY - initialOffsetY), limitOffsetY * (-1), limitOffsetY);
            if (Math.abs(targetOffsetX) === Math.abs(limitOffsetX)) {
                initialOffsetX = targetOffsetX;
                initialPointerOffsetX = pointerOffsetX;
            }
            if (Math.abs(targetOffsetY) === Math.abs(limitOffsetY)) {
                initialOffsetY = targetOffsetY;
                initialPointerOffsetY = pointerOffsetY;
            }
            $element.setAttribute(_dataScale, initialScale);
            $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateX, targetOffsetX);
            $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateY, targetOffsetY);
            moveScaleElement($element, targetOffsetX + "px", targetOffsetY + "px", targetScale);
        }
    }
    function touchEnd(e) {
        touchCount = e.touches.length;
        if (capture === false) {
            return false;
        }
        if (touchCount === 0) {
            $element.setAttribute(_dataScale, initialScale);
            $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateX, targetOffsetX);
            $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateY, targetOffsetY);
            initialPinchDistance = null;
            capture = false;
        } else if (touchCount === 1) /* Single touch */ {
            initialPointerOffsetX = e.touches[0].clientX;
            initialPointerOffsetY = e.touches[0].clientY;
        } else if (touchCount > 1) /* Pinch */ {
            initialPinchDistance = null;
        }
    }
    function wheel(e) {
        $container = this;
        $element = this.children[0];
        offset = $container.getBoundingClientRect();
        containerHeight = $container.clientHeight;
        containerWidth = $container.clientWidth;
        elementHeight = $element.clientHeight;
        elementWidth = $element.clientWidth;
        containerOffsetX = offset.left;
        containerOffsetY = offset.top;
        initialScale = minMax(parseFloat($element.getAttribute(_dataScale), C_scaleMin, C_scaleMax));
        initialOffsetX = parseFloat($element.getAttribute(_dataTranslateX));
        initialOffsetY = parseFloat($element.getAttribute(_dataTranslateY));
        pointerOffsetX = e.clientX;
        pointerOffsetY = e.clientY;
        scaleDirection = e.deltaY < 0 ? 1 : -1;
        scaleDifference = C_scaleDifference * scaleDirection;
        targetScale = initialScale + scaleDifference;
        if (targetScale < C_scaleMin || targetScale > C_scaleMax) {
            return false;
        }
        limitOffsetX = ((elementWidth * targetScale) - containerWidth) / 2;
        limitOffsetY = ((elementHeight * targetScale) - containerHeight) / 2;
        if (targetScale <= 1) {
            targetOffsetX = 0;
            targetOffsetY = 0;
        } else {
            targetOffsetX = (elementWidth * targetScale) <= containerWidth ? 0 : minMax(initialOffsetX - ((((((pointerOffsetX - containerOffsetX) - (containerWidth / 2)) - initialOffsetX) / (targetScale - scaleDifference))) * scaleDifference), limitOffsetX * (-1), limitOffsetX);
            targetOffsetY = (elementHeight * targetScale) <= containerHeight ? 0 : minMax(initialOffsetY - ((((((pointerOffsetY - containerOffsetY) - (containerHeight / 2)) - initialOffsetY) / (targetScale - scaleDifference))) * scaleDifference), limitOffsetY * (-1), limitOffsetY);
        }
        if (targetScale > 1) {
            addClass($container, _active);
        } else {
            removeClass($container, _active);
        }
        $element.setAttribute(_dataScale, targetScale);
        $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateX, targetOffsetX);
        $element.setAttribute(_dataTranslateY, targetOffsetY);
        moveScaleElement($element, targetOffsetX + "px", targetOffsetY + "px", targetScale);
    }
}
function addClass($element, targetClass) {
    if (hasClass($element, targetClass) === false) {
        $element.className += " " + targetClass;
    }
}
function disableScroll() {
    if (window.addEventListener)
    {
        window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    }
    window.onwheel = preventDefault;
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault;
    window.ontouchmove = preventDefault;
    document.onkeydown = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}
function enableScroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null;
    window.onwheel = null;
    window.ontouchmove = null;
    document.onkeydown = null;
}
function isWithinRange(value, min, max) {
    if (value >= min && value <= max) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function hasClass($element, targetClass) {
    var rgx = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + targetClass + "(?!\\S)", "g");
    if ($element.className.match(rgx)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function massAddEventListener($elements, event, customFunction, useCapture) {
    var useCapture = useCapture || false;
    for (var i = 0; i < $elements.length; i++) {
        $elements[i].addEventListener(event, customFunction, useCapture);
    }
}
function minMax(value, min, max) {
    if (value < min) {
        value = min;
    } else if (value > max) {
        value = max;
    }
    return value;
}
function moveScaleElement($element, targetOffsetX, targetOffsetY, targetScale) {
    $element.style.cssText = "-moz-transform : translate(" + targetOffsetX + ", " + targetOffsetY + ") scale(" + targetScale + "); -ms-transform : translate(" + targetOffsetX + ", " + targetOffsetY + ") scale(" + targetScale + "); -o-transform : translate(" + targetOffsetX + ", " + targetOffsetY + ") scale(" + targetScale + "); -webkit-transform : translate(" + targetOffsetX + ", " + targetOffsetY + ") scale(" + targetScale + "); transform : translate3d(" + targetOffsetX + ", " + targetOffsetY + ", 0) scale3d(" + targetScale + ", " + targetScale + ", 1);";
}
function preventDefault(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    e.returnValue = false;
}
function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    var keys = {
        37: 1,
        38: 1,
        39: 1,
        40: 1
    };
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    }
}
function removeClass($element, targetClass) {
    var rgx = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + targetClass + "(?!\\S)", "g");

    $element.className = $element.className.replace(rgx, "");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- insert <div class="zoom"> indirectly with javascript through class "img"-->
<a class="img" href="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-SrY4SGEWA0U/XkzC8iFrPWI/AAAAAAAAFck/pj319hsOteYRIVjJ2Z8RNJ5y_fjr_e8xQCKgBGAsYHg/s1600/ban-nha-duong-so-59-phuong-14-quan-go-vap-2.jpg">
<img border="0" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-SrY4SGEWA0U/XkzC8iFrPWI/AAAAAAAAFck/pj319hsOteYRIVjJ2Z8RNJ5y_fjr_e8xQCKgBGAsYHg/s1600/ban-nha-duong-so-59-phuong-14-quan-go-vap-2.jpg"/>
</a>

<!-- insert <div class = "zoom"> directly-->
<div class="zoom">
<a href="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-SrY4SGEWA0U/XkzC8iFrPWI/AAAAAAAAFck/pj319hsOteYRIVjJ2Z8RNJ5y_fjr_e8xQCKgBGAsYHg/s1600/ban-nha-duong-so-59-phuong-14-quan-go-vap-2.jpg">
<img border="0" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-SrY4SGEWA0U/XkzC8iFrPWI/AAAAAAAAFck/pj319hsOteYRIVjJ2Z8RNJ5y_fjr_e8xQCKgBGAsYHg/s1600/ban-nha-duong-so-59-phuong-14-quan-go-vap-2.jpg"/>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why use `a` tags if you dont want the behaviour of `a` tags?

Comment: Hi @Lain, I want to use `a` tag to create event that click on image. Then execute the javascript below.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `event.preventDefault();` to prevent  click default;

```
$('a.img').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
```

See document 
https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Thanks buddy but it's not working :( I think the problem is in the pinch / zoom code.

Comment: I could not understand what is your problem here, you mean when you click `$('a.img')`, code on click function is not working  or `function zoom` not working with new your `<div class="zoom"><img border="0" src="'+link_img+'"` ?

Comment: Other thing on your code, I see when you add <div class="zoom"> directly you wrap image by `<a>` tag, but on javascript , on click event, you only insert `<img>` without `<a>` tag ?